# Pattern matching in Postgres SELECT query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in by database that has a `name` field with a non-null and unique constraint.

On the frontend, a user can clone certain entities. In this scenario, the `name` field gets suffixed with a version number.

For instance, if record A exists with the name `TEST_NAME`, cloning this record would result in record B being created with the name `TEST_NAME [2]`. Cloning record A again would result in a record C with the name `TEST_NAME [3]`.

To determine the version number, I run a `count(*)` against the table, returning the number of records that match the root name, in this case: `'TEST_NAME'`.

Here is the query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
WHERE name LIKE 'TEST_NAME%'
```

The issue here, is that if a user changes the name of record C to `TEST_NAME [3]abc`, then the above query would still pick this up and create record D with the name `TEST_NAME [4]`, instead of `TEST_NAME [3]abc [2]`.

How can I avoid this? I'd like to only match `name` values that follow the format `^TEST_NAME [x]$`, where `x` is any integer.

Comment: PostgreSQL has support for Regexes :-) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL has support for regexes.

For instance, I guess what you need is

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
WHERE name ~ '^TEST_NAME \[[0-9]+\]$'
```

For computing the next version, I propose the following :

```
SELECT
  version,
  COALESCE(
    matches[1] || ' [' || matches[2]::int + 1 || ']',
    matches[3] || ' [2]'
  ) AS nextVersion
FROM versions
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT regexp_matches(version, '^(.*) \[([0-9]+)\]$|^(.*)$') matches
) t
```

Here is what's going on :

For each version, we match the regexp ^(.*)[([0-9]+)]$|^(.*)$. Groups 1 and 2 will be populated if the version ends with a version number. Group 3 always contains the whole name. We put this result in the lateral table t(matches).

If group 1 and 2 have values, then "matches[1] || ' [' || matches[2]::int + 1 || ']'" is the next version, otherwise pick matches[3] and add [2] to it.

As a bonus, the following query will give the last version for every rootname, and the next version available.

```
SELECT rootname, MAX(t2.version) AS lastVersion, MAX(t2.version) + 1 AS nextVersion
FROM versions
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT regexp_matches(version, '^(.*) \[([0-9]+)\]$|^(.*)$') matches
) t1
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT
    COALESCE(matches[1], matches[3]) AS rootname,
    COALESCE(matches[2]::int, 1) AS version
) t2
GROUP BY rootname;
```

If you just have a rootname (say TEST_NAME), and assuming you only have one column version in your table which would be called versions, you can clone the record using :

```
INSERT INTO versions
SELECT rootname || ' [' || MAX(t2.version) + 1 || ']'
FROM versions
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT regexp_matches(version, '^(.*) \[([0-9]+)\]$|^(.*)$') matches
) t1
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT
    COALESCE(matches[1], matches[3]) AS rootname,
    COALESCE(matches[2]::int, 1) AS version
) t2
WHERE rootname = 'TEST_NAME';
```

Comment: You have to modify the search expression to `'^TEST_NAME \[[0-9]{1,}\]$'` to get `TEST_NAME [99]` or `TEST_NAME [999]` too

Comment: @Philippe, I think this is the same as the "+" I put after [0-9] :-)

Comment: Yes you're right. Was the "+" there in the first version ? Haven't seen it. Something wrong with my eyes ;)  Apologize !!!

Comment: No worries! :-D